# SOLR - Searching record based on SOLR field in passed string

Tags: solr

I have a CSV string field say "field1" in SOLR which can have value similar to 1,5,7

Now, I want to get this record if I pass values:

1,5,6,7
OR 
1,5,7,10
OR
1,5,7

Basically any of these inputs should return me this record from SOLR.

Is there anyway to achieve this. I am open for schema change if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [Standard Tokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/tokenizers.html) (used in text fields like `text_general`) will not split on commas if there is no space in between characters.

That means that "1,2,3" will be indexed as a single token ("1,2,3") but it will index "1, 2, 3" as three tokens ("1", "2", "3").

**If you can make sure there will be a space after the comma in the value that you are indexing and the value that you are using in your search query** you might be able to achieve what you want by indexing your field as a `text_general`.

You can use the [Analysis Screen](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/analysis-screen.html) in Solr to see how your value will be indexed and searched and see if any of the built-in field types gives you what you want.